# matplotlib: equal axes and 0/0 at lower left corner

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot some data in an equal-spaced plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = 2 * x

plt.figure(figsize=(2, 3), dpi=100)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axline((0,0), slope=1, linestyle=':')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

[image: origin is in lower left corner]

In this example, the origin (0/0) is in the lower left corner and the 1:1 line passes right through the corner.
However, if I change the size of the figure just slightly, either the x or y axis will start on a different location:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=100)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axline((0,0), slope=1, linestyle=':')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

[image: origin not at left lower corner]

Is it possible to enforce both an equal spacing on both axes but also keep the origin (in my case always 0/0) in the lower left corner?

Comment: `plt.gca().axis('square')`?

Comment: @Mr.T this will enforce the plot to be squared, which I do not necessarily want. The latter `figsize=(3,3)` is unfortunately a special case. I changed that in the question

Comment: Maybe `plt.xlim(xmin=plt.ylim()[0],xmax=plt.ylim()[1]*ratio)`?  With `bbox = plt.gca().get_window_extent()` and `ratio = bbox.width/bbox.height`.

Comment: @JohanC yes! That works great! However it needs some adjustments if y is the longer axis - but I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the limits on the x and y axis using `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` should solve the problem

checkout https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html

Comment: If the plot has an equal aspect ration, setting the limits will also change the size of the plot - at least in my example above it does. Do not setting the aspect to `equal` and then setting the limits works, however then one has to calculate the correct spacing for each axis to keep the axes equal.